# Deleting object from a stack

Tags: c++, delete-operator

Is it bad/illegal C++ to delete manually objects from a stack or there are situation when it is acceptable?

*Edit*

```
Constructor(pointer parent, pointer left, pointer right):parent_(parent),left_(left), right_(right)
{   }

   ~Constructor()
        {
        delete parent_;
        delete left_;
        delete right_;
        }


main()
{
Object parent;
Object left;
Object right;
Constructor c(&parent,&left,&right);
}
```

**Is there any way to check if object is on heap or on stack?**

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by 'stack'? Is it the implicit stack used by local vars and such, or a container (STL?)?

Comment: @jv42 and why would it be bad/illegal C++ to delete manually object from std::stack ?

Comment: If you're going to post code, which you should, please at least post real code.

Comment: @John and what's wrong with pseudocode?

Comment: @John but what the heck I've changed it.

Comment: @There: I just don't get what you're trying to express.  For example, in the destructor you do `delete parent_` but I cant tell what `parent_` is or where it came from.  The psudocode seems to suggest it is a pointer, which in turn might suggest it was the result of a `new` expression. In that case, the `delete` is legal and in many cases proper.  But that's not a stack variable, so it has nothing to do with your stated question.  See my confusion?  If you post real code I can compile, then there's no ambiguity and we can have a detailed conversaton about it.

Comment: @John it is real code or can be anyway. What confuses you? You have pointers to objects and then in main you have objects created on stack and their addresses taken for ctor args. What confuses you?

Comment: @There:  Where did the pointers come from?

Comment: @There: Oh, now I see.  Yes, the code you posted is both illegal and very bad.

Comment: @John the nature of the question is that it doesn't require (at list I thought so) a code. It was simple yes or no answer to that question: yes it's bad/illegal or no it's ok. I've made up this pseudo-code as a short and brief reply to Starkey just to visualise what I've meant. Pseudo-code is best for this kind of purpouses. As for answer to your question: typedef Object* pointer;

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: there are lots of people asking strange questions here, yours wasn't very specific, it needed more info.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: On the particular issue of *why would it be bad/illegal C++ to delete manually an object from an std::stack?* The answer is that you are not responsible for the management of that memory, and as such you should not delete. It will cause Undefined Behavior as the container will try to free the resource itself (double delete) and because in most cases the pointer you might get is not a pointer returned from a call to `new` (the stored object can either be a subelement of an array or a subobject in a node, depending on the underlying container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is bad to `delete` automatic variables (ie, objects on the stack).  I suppose there is still no "never" in programming, but I can't think of a time/reason why you would want to do this.

What scenario are you thinking of?

EDIT:  Actually, not only is it bad, it is illegal:

### 5.3.5 Delete

> 1: The delete-expression operator
>   destroys a most derived object (1.8)
>   or array created by a new-expression.

Comment: @Roger no I mean stack as opposite to heap.

Comment: @John Dibling Thanks that is what I wanted to know. Illegal. Great.

Comment: @There: You updated the question with code so I deleted the comment (before I saw your reply); you may want to change "a stack" (for everyone else: I thought this could mean something like std::stack, and deleting objects owned by containers is bad) to "the stack".

Comment: What about deleting an object created by placement new? This should be illegal/undefined, right? Or is the terminology such that placement new doesn't create an object?

Comment: @Philipp:  Do not `delete` object created with placement `new`.  You should only `delete` the original buffer.  There is no "placement delete".  See here:  http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#placement-delete

Comment: @Philipp: That's an ambiguity in the current standard, but you should understand it as placement-new being separate from the others.  Only pointers obtained from (non-placement-)new—where you've followed all the relevant rules (including that manual dtor calls match up with placement-new and other object lifetime rules)—can be deleted.

Comment: @Philipp: *placement-new* is a way of calling a constructor, and the reverse operation is calling the destructor, not calling `delete`. `void foo( void * buffer ) { new (buffer) Type; ... ; static_cast<Type*>(buffer)->~Type(); }`

Answer (score 12):

You are only allowed to `delete` those objects that have been allocated with `new`. If you try to call `delete` on a pointer pointing to an object on the stack, you will probably crash your program.

Answer (score 1):

There is one corner case, which I can think of, where it is OK to delete the local object manually.

```
struct A{
    A(){}
    int x;
    ~A(){}
};

int main(){
    char buf[sizeof(A)];
    A *p = new(buf)A();
    p->~A();
}
```

Comment: There is no `delete` call here?

Comment: but you NOT DELETING you are destroying in that case.

Comment: Not sure why it is downvoted. The OP never asked about using delete. It was about deleting the object.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but your code doesn't delete the object.  There is no way your response is relevant to the OP's question.  Not my downvote, JSYK.

Comment: If "the OP never asked about using delete", then why does he say "deleting" twice and use "delete" 3 times in his code?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you will have a method which allows you to edit the stack and usually the actual stack isn't exposed to the outside world to be manipulated outside the accessors defined on the class.  So I'd say it is bad because there could be other properties and state inside the object representing the stack that become unsynced when you remove items manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know that ownership is transferred, then don't use raw pointers.  Use smart pointers, such as std::auto_ptr (Boost and C++0x have many more) which make the transfer of ownership explicit and additionally convey how to destroy the objects (for auto_ptr this means delete):

```
struct Example {
  Example(std::auto_ptr<T> parent, std::auto_ptr<TObject> left,
          std::auto_ptr<T> right)
  : _parent (parent), _left (left), _right (right)
  {}

private:
  std::auto_ptr<T> _parent, _left, _right;
};
```

You could still store raw pointers, if you really insist, by using auto_ptr's release method and writing a copy ctor, destructor, and assignment operator for Example (the Rule of Three).

Answer (score 0):

Use references instead of pointers.